# How do I show a programmatically set layout on the first draw?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have this LinearLayout that is a child of a RelativeLayout along with a ListView among other things:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/color_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/space_used_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#006688"
        android:padding="0dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/space_free_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444444"
        android:padding="0dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't intend to put any text in those TextViews; they are simply there for their background color values. I want to set the width's of these two TextViews programmatically, which I can do, but the problem is that the first time the LinearLayout is presented, it is not drawn. It has no size and I also cannot see the TextViews contained within it. When the user does almost anything (e.g. lock the screen, press the home button, click a list item, select an options item, etc.) the TextViews display properly. It's just that at the first moment when the activity opens, the TextViews and the Layout doesn't show up at all. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

P.S. I have already tried calling invalidate on the LinearLayout as well as the individual TextViews.

EDIT: Here are the callbacks

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
    topMenu = getActionBar();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.file_list);
    spaceUsedBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.space_used_bar);
    spaceFreeBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.space_free_bar);
    spaceUsed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.space_used);
    spaceFree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.space_free);
    colorBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.color_bar);
    stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            currentDirectory = externalStorageDirectory;
        else
        {
            currentDirectory = new File(ROOT_DIR);
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(c, R.string.not_mounted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentDirectory = new File(savedInstanceState.getString("savedPath"));
        int savedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("savedPosition");
        int savedListTop = savedInstanceState.getInt("savedListTop");
        if (savedPosition >= 0)
            lv.setSelectionFromTop(savedPosition, savedListTop);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    //Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");

    super.onStart();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
    browseTo(currentDirectory);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    //Log.d(TAG, "onResume()");

    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you haven't redrawn the layout after setting a new width for the TextViews and when the system redraws the layout after the user leaves then returns (locking the screen, home button, orientation change, etc). But I don't see your onCreate() and onResume() code, so it is only a guess...

Comment: Yea that's the part that baffles me. I've gone through all the code that happens between when they don't show up until they do, and it seems to be completely arbitrary. I'll post the code soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but try one of the following (on the textviews).  For instance you assign it some initial width or weight, and then adjust it accordingly programmatically when that code executes...

```
android:layout_width="40dp"
```

If you want them to take up a percent of the screen instead use the weight attribute:

```
android:layout_weight="2"
```

Comment: Yes I've done this and while it will make them show up, they are not the widths I specified in my code. They first show up as defined by the layout then changes later to the sizes specified through my code.